# update list object from a list of linq queried objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, gridview

I have a GridView DataSource that is a linq query to a List in the Session.

```
List<Invoice> returnInvoices = (List<Invoice>)Session["Invoices"];

    var partInvoices = from i in returnInvoices
                       where i.PartNo == partNo
                       select new
                       {
                           i.InvoiceID,
                           i.InvoiceNo,
                           i.InvoiceLine,
                           i.InvoiceDate,
                           i.OrderNo,
                           i.OrderLine,
                           i.OrderRel,
                           i.OrderLineItem,
                           i.OrderLineQty,
                           i.CustomerPO,
                           i.Serialized
                       };

    GridView3.DataSource = partInvoices;
    GridView3.DataBind();
```

When I select a row from the GridView, I need to update the related object in the original session list, which contains more objects than the GridView. (ie, invoices for all parts, not just the part in the linq query)

My question is, how to I relate the selected object in the GridView back to the original list? I wanted to use GridView.SelectedIndex but this wont work because 0 on GridView could well be 382 on the original list!

I'm a bit stuck and not sure how to do this, any help or advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: If you have the InvoiceId in the GridView, can you not use that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861873/gridview-databind-with-linq-query-errors ??

Comment: @humpty yes i had an issue with the source coming back as null. which is now OK, but now i need to know how to edit the object that i've selected from the gridview, in the original list.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to find the object in your session with invoiceid and update the properties that were updated through grid.

Comment: i'm sorry i'm very new to linq (as in, just start using it an hour ago, this is my first linq query!).
how would i use linq to query the list of objects again but to update the object rather than bind it to a gridview? this is what confuses me...

Answer (score 0):

Just don't create new objects (of an anonymous type) in the query, instead bind to the actual objects.

```
List<Invoice> returnInvoices = (List<Invoice>)Session["Invoices"];

var partInvoices = returnInvoices
                       .Where(invoice => invoice.PartNo == partNo)
                       .ToList();

GridView3.DataSource = partInvoices;
GridView3.DataBind();
```

If this is not possible for some reasons things will start to become a bit messy. You could store a mapping between the actual object and the object create in the LINQ query in a dictionary or something like that but the best solution really depends on your needs.